# Gparted showing the whole disk

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, gparted

The title says it all, I do not see any partition but the whole disk. My version is 12.04 LTS. I literally have no idea.

Comment: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img838/2808/p2fg.png

Here is the picture, When I installed ubuntu, I put /home, /swap and root to different partitions and I also have Win 7, so it is IMPOSSIBLE for me to have no partition

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img834/3923/mwpr.png

Well, it shows one partition but the size of one of them is wrong also, I can access all my partitions

Comment: What does GParted show if you double-click on the device which shows an exclamation point beside it?  You can also get similar information from the command:  sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print.  I suspect there is a problem with the partition table.  If so then see [How-to Fix Invalid MSDOS Partition Tables](http://gparted.org/h2-fix-msdos-pt.php).

Comment: It says "Can't have overlapping partitions"
is there any way I can fix this without wiping my data?

Comment: But it's solution is dubious, does that mean it is going to wipe my windows partition?